# Git Bash Prompt- Current Branch Name Stops Showing After Git Command

Tags: git, git-bash

Using GitBash with Git for Windows, my PS1 variable is set to display current branch as such:

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$
```

This works fine to start, for example my prompt starts out like

```
myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/git/myrepo (master)
$
```

However, after I run any git command, the current branch portion is omitted until I restart the shell.

```
myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/git/myrepo (master)
$ git branch
* master
  myOtherBranch

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/git/myrepo
$
```

But if I run __git_ps1 it still tells me the correct value:

```
myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/git/myrepo
$ echo `__git_ps1`
(master)

myuser@mypc MINGW64 /c/git/myrepo
$
```

Any ideas what could be happening, or how I could go about diagnosing/fixing this issue?

Comment: I have the same `PS1` value and don't observe this behavior.  After you run a git command but before restarting the shell (i.e. while it is not showing the branch name), have you verified that the `PS1` value is still as you expect? (It shouldn't change, but perhaps an alias is set up that's doing something it shouldn't; is there someone that might have had access to your profile, that might be playing a little joke?)

Comment: I did, yes. The value is identical before and after running a command. Another fact I should probably mention is that this was working fine earlier, but stopped working after upgrading from version 2.8.0.windows.1 to 2.12.0.windows.1.

Comment: Just did a test upgrade of one of my systems to 2.12.0.windows.1 (64bit) and still can't reproduce the issue.  Version might be a factor, but there must be more to it.

Comment: I'm not really surprised - if everyone was seeing it there would be results in Google search. I guess as a Bash noob I was wondering if anyone knew a way to get some diagnostics on it to dig deeper.

Comment: Rolled back to previous version of Git and things are working fine again. I don't really need the upgrade so I'm not going to investigate anymore.

Comment: I've been having the same issue with my work PC. Just recently started happening so I assume I was pushed some upgrade since I am on the  2.12.0.windows.1 version. Its a pretty annoying issue for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I was able to get things working again based off [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245548/git-ps1-current-branch-in-bash-prompt-is-always-out-of-date-somehow) and the info already here in this question. I added the below to my *.bashrc* file and all is good once again. I'm not sure what the root cause of the issue might be, but this seems to be a good workaround for me.

```
update_PS1 () {
  PS1="\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:${PWD//[^[:ascii:]]/?}\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$ "
}
shopt -u promptvars
PROMPT_COMMAND=update_PS1
```

Comment: it's giving me this error:
bash: __git_ps1: command not found

Comment: For me, make the `gitstatus.sh` file executable solved the problem. 

FYI I am using https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.  After I run any git command, the current branch name is disappear. First I use the tip from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43659303/8156156. Works well.

But after investigation I find that I have not only this problem but other with bash. I write it in https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1153#issuecomment-308110681.

I don't know a root of these problems but workaround that works for me (for both problems) is install 32-bit version of Git for Windows (Git-2.13.1-32-bit).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu: Show your branch name on your terminal
Add these lines in your ~/.bashrc file

```
# Show git branch name
force_color_prompt=yes
color_prompt=yes
parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Close and open your terminal

Comment: For Windows GitBash you can remove the `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` as it is not needed.   Worked well for me after my branch stopped appearing today after an OS update.

Answer (score -1):

All I had to do is place a blank line at the end of .bashrc, and that solved it.